# In Nifi, how do I create a JSON flow file from a list of tags and a file containing all of the records, one record per line?

Tags: json, field, apache-nifi, record, flowfile

I have a semicolon-delimited file containing 1000 records, one record per line, with each record containing several fields delimited by semicolons.  I also have a list of tags for the fields in the records.  How do I combine these into a JSON flow file in NiFi?

Semicolon-delimited data file:

```
r1f1;r1f2;r1f3;r1f4;r1f5
r2f1;r2f2;r2f3;r2f4;r2f5
r3f1;f3r2;r3f3;r3f4;r3f5
...
```

List of field tags:

```
f1_tag, f2_tag, f3_tag, f4_tag, f5_tag
```

I can enter the list of tags into a processor block, but I am not sure which processor, if any, I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty basic. Use `ConvertRecord` with `CSVReader` as the `Record Reader` (don't forget to configure it to use semicolon as the `Value Separator`!) and set the `Record Writer` to be `JsonRecordSetWriter` and there you have it!

By the way, don't forget to add a header row!

[image]
[image]
[image: final result]